# How do i merge the arrays in a particular format?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have following arrays:

1) for total placed

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => delhi
                [id] => 1
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totalplaced] => 8
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => mumbai
                [id] => 2
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totalplaced] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

2) for total working

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => delhi
                [id] => 1
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totalworking] => 4
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => mumbai
                [id] => 2
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totalworking] => 1
            )

    )

 )
```

3) for total trained

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => delhi
                [id] => 1
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totaltrained] => 8
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => mumbai
                [id] => 2
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [totaltrained] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

I wanted to merge these arrays so that the resultant array should look like this

```
[newarray] => Array(
[0] => Array (
    [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => delhi
                [id] => 1
                [totalplaced] => 8
                [totalworking] => 4
                [totaltrained] => 8
             )
  )
[1]=> Array(
   [centers] => Array
            (
                [name] => mumbai
                [id] => 2
                [totalplaced] => 1
                [totalworking] => 1
                [totaltrained] => 1
             )
    )
 )
```

This is the tabular representation of the above data which i want to display

```
centername      totalplaced    totalworking   totaltrained 
  delhi             8               4             8
  mumbai            1               1             1
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Pankaj Khurana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that PHP's functions such as array_merge() and array_merge_recursive() will not merge data into numeric keys, but rather will re-key any duplicate numeric key. So for example given two arrays:

```
array(
  'test' => 'abc',
  0 => 'xyz'
);

array(
  'test' => 'def',
  0 => 'uvw'
);
```

Merging them together with array_merge() will produce an array like:

```
array(
  'test' => 'def',
  0 => 'xyz',
  1 => 'uvw'
);
```

So, you need a custom function to be "additive" on any key, regardless of whether it is a string or numeric key. Try this:

```
function mixed_key_array_merge() {

  $args = func_get_args();

  $result = array();

  foreach ($args as $arg) {

    // discard non-array arguments; maybe this could be better handled
    if (!is_array($arg)) {
      continue;
    }

    foreach ($arg as $key => $value) {

      if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
      } else if (is_array($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = call_user_func_array('mixed_key_array_merge',array($result[$key],$value));
      }

    }

  }

  return $result;

}
```